# Undefined Reference GTK Functions using GCC

Tags: c++, batch-file, gcc, gtk, gtk3

I am using GTK+ 3.x and MinWG GCC in Windows 7. I have all the paths set and everything works up to compiling where it errors out with Undefined References.

```
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8N3tch.o:helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x7): undefined reference to `gtk_main_quit'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8N3tch.o:helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x41): undefined reference to `gtk_init_abi_check'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8N3tch.o:helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x4d): undefined reference to `gtk_window_new'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8N3tch.o:helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x85): undefined reference to `g_signal_connect_data'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8N3tch.o:helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x91): undefined reference to `gtk_label_new'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8N3tch.o:helloworld.cpp:(.text+0x9a): undefined reference to `gtk_container_get_type'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8N3tch.o:helloworld.cpp:(.text+0xae): undefined reference to `g_type_check_instance_cast'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8N3tch.o:helloworld.cpp:(.text+0xbe): undefined reference to `gtk_container_add'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8N3tch.o:helloworld.cpp:(.text+0xca): undefined reference to `gtk_widget_show'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8N3tch.o:helloworld.cpp:(.text+0xd6): undefined reference to `gtk_widget_show'
C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8N3tch.o:helloworld.cpp:(.text+0xdb): undefined reference to `gtk_main'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: C:\Users\user\AppData\Local\Temp\cc8N3tch.o: bad reloc address 0x20 in section `.eh_frame'
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/4.8.1/../../../../mingw32/bin/ld.exe: final link failed: Invalid operation
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Using sample code from GTK's website

```
#include <gtk/gtk.h>

static void on_window_closed(GtkWidget * widget, gpointer data)
{
    gtk_main_quit();
}

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    GtkWidget * window, * label;

    gtk_init(&argc, &argv);

    window = gtk_window_new(GTK_WINDOW_TOPLEVEL);

    g_signal_connect( window, "destroy", G_CALLBACK(on_window_closed), NULL);

    label = gtk_label_new("Hello, World!");

    gtk_container_add(GTK_CONTAINER(window), label);

    gtk_widget_show(label);
    gtk_widget_show(window);

    gtk_main();

    return 0;
}
```

The batch file I use to build it

```
@echo off

set gtk_ver=gtk+-3.0
pkg-config %gtk_ver% --cflags --libs >tmp.txt
set /p pkg-info= <tmp.txt
del tmp.txt

rem echo &pkg-info%
gcc -o helloworld helloworld.cpp %pkg-info%
```

This is what the tmp.txt file looks like before it is deleted

```
-mms-bitfields -IC:/gtk/include/gtk-3.0 -IC:/gtk/include/cairo -IC:/gtk/include/pango-1.0 -IC:/gtk/include/atk-1.0 -IC:/gtk/include/cairo -IC:/gtk/include/pixman-1 -IC:/gtk/include -IC:/gtk/include/freetype2 -IC:/gtk/include -IC:/gtk/include/libpng15 -IC:/gtk/include/gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:/gtk/include/libpng15 -IC:/gtk/include/glib-2.0 -IC:/gtk/lib/glib-2.0/include -LC:/gtk/lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpango-1.0 -lm -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

I have tried editing the batch to run the gcc different ways but all fail.

```
gcc %pkg-info% helloworld.cpp -o helloworld
gcc helloworld.cpp -o %pkg-info% helloworld //Gives me helloworld: no such file or directory
gcc helloworld -o %pkg-info% helloworld.cpp //Gives me helloworld: no such file or directory
gcc helloworld.cpp %pkg-info% -o helloworld
```

The reason I use a batch file is because using `` `pkg-config --libs --cflags gtk+-3.0` `` fails, giving the error that pkg-config does not exist. Running pkg-config on the cl, not with gcc, works fine.

pk-config from Mofi's batch file.

```
-mms-bitfields -IC:\gtk\include\gtk-3.0 -IC:\gtk\include\cairo -IC:\gtk\include\pango-1.0 -IC:\gtk\include\atk-1.0 -IC:\gtk\include\cairo -IC:\gtk\include\pixman-1 -IC:\gtk\include -IC:\gtk\include\freetype2 -IC:\gtk\include -IC:\gtk\include\libpng15 -IC:\gtk\include\gdk-pixbuf-2.0 -IC:\gtk\include\libpng15 -IC:\gtk\include\glib-2.0 -IC:\gtk\lib\glib-2.0\include -LC:\gtk\lib -lgtk-3 -lgdk-3 -lgdi32 -limm32 -lshell32 -lole32 -Wl,-luuid -lpangocairo-1.0 -lpangoft2-1.0 -lfreetype -lfontconfig -lpangowin32-1.0 -lgdi32 -lpango-1.0 -lm -latk-1.0 -lcairo-gobject -lcairo -lgdk_pixbuf-2.0 -lgio-2.0 -lgobject-2.0 -lglib-2.0 -lintl
```

Mofi's batch file with full paths

```
@echo off
rem Get all options for build into an environment variable.
set "gtk_ver=gtk+-3.0"
"C:\gtk\bin\pkg-config.exe" %gtk_ver% --cflags --libs >"%TEMP%\gtk_options.tmp"
set /p pkg-info=<"%TEMP%\gtk_options.tmp"

rem Replace all / by \ in the environment variable.
set "pkg-info=%pkg-info:/=\%"
del %TEMP%\gtk_options.tmp

rem echo %pkg-info%
"C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe" %pkg-info% -o helloworld helloworld.c

PAUSE
```

You can [download](http://www.filedropper.com/tmp) a text file of the gtk directory. (Sorry if it is full of ads. It's a free file drop place. Unknown how long it will last. Will update when it's dropped)

Comment: @Mofi those are all linker errors; the error log wouldn't even be reaching that point if `<gtk/gtk.h>` isn't found.

Comment: @Mofi I don't make the includes. That is the output of the `pkg-config` command.

Comment: I have looked once more on the error messages and have seen now that the problem is not on compile stage, but on linking the object files. The options output by `pkg-config` contains just `-LC:/gtk/lib` to define the directory for the libraries and lots of `-l` to define all the library files. Do you have verified already if this directory exists and contains all the specified library files?

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if the batch file code below helps on this issue as I do not have access to your computer and see the directories and files. But give it a try.

```
@echo off
rem Get all options for build into an environment variable.
set "gtk_ver=gtk+-3.0"
"C:\gtk\bin\pkg-config.exe" %gtk_ver% --cflags --libs >"%TEMP%\gtk_options.tmp"
set /p pkg-info=<"%TEMP%\gtk_options.tmp"
del "%TEMP%\gtk_options.tmp"

rem Replace all / by \ in the environment variable.
set "pkg-info=%pkg-info:/=\%"

rem echo %pkg-info%
"C:\MinGW\bin\gcc.exe" helloworld.c -o helloworld %pkg-info%
```

**Edit:**

I have changed the order on last line calling GCC. The order is now

1. Source file to compile.
2. Name of output file to produce.
3. All other options from package configuration.

This edit was inspired by [Problem with compiling GTK3 program](https://askubuntu.com/questions/91505/problem-with-compiling-gtk3-program).

And I renamed the source file to **helloworld.c** as the file contains C and not C++ code. The file extension **cpp** results in an automatic compiling of the file as C++ file. This could result in the linker errors if **gtk.h** does not contain

```
#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

/* Function declarations */

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

Comment: I've updated my question to include a download link for a text file with the directories and files listed for gtk. Same errors occur when running your batch file.

Comment: Even after the edits, it's still not working. I think I'm going to find a different cross-platform gui library. Thanks for you help.

Answer (score 0):

in the tmp.txt file i am not seeing the `-lgtk-win32-3.0` flag ! , i think you're using the x64 package of gtk+ ,

if you're running a x64 windows download the x32 bundle of gtk+ instead of x64 ,

good luck,